# Catch Zero Rows Updated

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

I have the following code that is clearing the account logout flags for an application we use.

```
try
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=DBSERVER;Initial Catalog=AbraEmployeeSelfService;Integrated Security=False;user=FOO;pwd=BAR";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.tUSERS SET UserUnsuccessfulLoginCount = 0, UserLockoutInd = 0 WHERE LEFT(UserAbraSuiteLogicalPrimaryKey, 4) = '" + BadgeNumber + "'", connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

How can I get this to catch when zero rows are returned?

Comment: I would suggest that you use `SqlParameter` to pass as the badge number. Otherwise you might be exposed to Sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` will return the number of affected rows. Use that. :)

```
int nbUpdatedRows;

(...)

nbUpdatedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

(...)

if (nbUpdatedRows == 0) // do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` method returns the total number of rows effected after executing the command.

From MSDN : [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

You can check its return value to compare with zero.

Try This:

```
int status = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(status==0)
  MessageBox.Show("No Rows Updated!");
```

Comment: Do *not* throw SqlException, it would make no sense here.

Comment: @Crono: that is true but user want to throw exception when no rows are found -> `How can I get this to catch when zero rows are returned?`

Comment: I just needed the 'int status = command.ExecuteNonQuery();" line.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi even so, this won't work. You cannot create an instance of an `SqlException`.